# How to open Word files as a popup from PHP file?

Tags: microsoft-word

There are some hyperlinks in my `.php` file and these links are related to Microsoft Word files (all files are `.doc` files).

If I click on any link it should open in a popup window and will show the contents of the file.

Right now when I click on a link, it opens the Word file, but I want to open a popup window where the data will be displayed – without asking anything or opening any window that prompts the user for the application to open the particular document with. Same for .pdf, .txt, .psd (photoshop document) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Microsoft Word Viewer. It lets you open files without having to buy the program.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=4

Comment: I was just about to answer the same. This will solve the problem.

Comment: hi, I want to just open .doc (ms-word) file in a popup window

Comment: hey if you dont want to install anything then you can try uploading the file to the gmail and click on view to view it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a kind of behavior where the user clicks on a hyperlink and **no external program** opens, then you can **only** resort to displaying the Word files (or text, PSD, etc.) with HTML. You really have no other choice.

Anything else would require the user to have some kind of plugin (e.g. an [ActiveX viewer](http://microsoft1.software.informer.com/download-microsoft-word-activex-viewer/) for Windows users), which not all users might have installed. Especially with ActiveX, you'd shut out Linux and OS X users, for example.

So, what you need to do is:

- Read the files through PHP or any other server-side processing method (something [like here](http://view.samurajdata.se/))
- Convert their presentation to HTML (or SVG, HTML5 Canvas, anything else that a browser can display natively). This can be tricky, but there's no way around it.
- Open a popup with Javascript when the user clicks the link, and show them what you generated.

Comment: Hi, But program should run without any software/plugin installed. It doesn't matter user don't have ms-office for (.doc or word file)

Comment: Then you need to convert the files that should be displayed on the server that runs the PHP scripts, and output them in a native format that browsers can display. Usually, that'd be plain HTML or SVG. Basically, like Google Docs viewer does it.

Comment: Hi, 

But program should run without any software/plugin installed. 

It doesn't matter user don't have any plugin, MS-Office for (.doc or word file), and / or Acrobat Reader for running .pdf files.  Same with .psd (photoshop document).  If user doesn't has MS-Office, Acrobat Reader, Photoshop Software installed in his/her system, still the program will open .doc (word), .pdf, .psd (photoshop document) file in the popup window (The file format should not be change in the popup window).

Comment: Again, if the user who views the site cannot install any plugin or additional software that can display those formats natively, then *you* have to convert the files to HTML or something else a browser can display. I'm not sure what other information I can give you.

Comment: @slhck Good answer, too bad he doesn't understand what you're telling him..

Comment: @harish, Check out [GroupDocs viewer](http://groupdocs.com/apps/viewer) which can be called from PHP. It sounds just like the service you need.

Comment: Hi slhck,  Thanks for your reply. I will go through it today and if I need help regarding the same I will let you know. Thanks         Harish Chand Pathak